# Embedding IDs with active model serializers leaves out key names when using composite primary keys

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, composite-primary-key, active-model-serializers

I am using composite primary keys in my Ruby On Rails API server. I am also using Active Model Serializers to manage the serialization of my models. I would like to use the `embed: :ids` feature in my serializer to embed my IDs. This works with composite primary keys, but only gives the ID's values. Since there are multiple IDs for a single record, there is no way to know which value belongs to which column.

### My Serializer

```
class PostSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :title, :body
  has_many :comments, embed :ids
end
```

### Resulting JSON

```
{
  "post": {
    "id": 1,
    "title": "New post",
    "body": "A body!",
    "comment_ids": [ [1, "v1"], [1, "v2"], [2, "v1"] ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to work around this issue using Active Model Serilizer's `embed_key` option along with Composite Primary Key's `ids_hash` method.

### My Serializer

```
class PostSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :title, :body
  has_many :comments, embed :ids, embed_keys: :ids_hash
end
```

### Resulting JSON

```
{
  "post": {
    "id": 1,
    "title": "New post",
    "body": "A body!",
    "comment_ids": [
      {"comment_id": 1, "version_id": "v1"},
      {"comment_id": 1, "version_id": "v2"},
      {"comment_id": 2, "version_id": "v1"},
    ]
  }
}
```